# Create a MAC OS Application for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: macos, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I want to develop a MAC OS standalone application which should talk to my Microsoft Dynamics CRM Instance. It should do basic operations like Create Marketing List, RetrieveMultiple on Contacts and Add Contacts to Marketing List.

With Windows Application, we use the SDK to create instance of the Organization Service.

Can I use the Organization Service or Web API with MAC OS Application?

Comment: Short answer is - yes you can, it's simply a web interface so you can consume it from wherever you want. How to do that is another story, and it's too broad for a SO question...

Comment: SO i can use the CRM Web API on the Mac OS platform to perform CRM Operations. Can you please help me by giving some pointer on how to do a simple create contact functionality on the Mac Os Application. Thank you very much for your reply.